# return true if the passed item is present in all the arrays inside arrayOfArrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am having trouble checking if item is present in all of the arrays inside `arrayOfArrays`.

I am trying to use the `includes` method to solve this problem as below:

```
function isItemHere(arrayOfArrays, item) {
  return arrayOfArrays.includes(item);
}
```

However, this does not work.

Comment: you have to use includes method or other equivalent for all arrays inside `arrayOfArrays`

Answer (score 3):

For a single 1D array you code will work. But for 2D array you can use `every()`

```
arrayOfArrays.every(x => x.includes(item));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using just `includes` is not going to work, as `myArray.includes(item)` checks if `item` exists at least one time in `myArray` (**not** in every child of `myArray`). If you have an array of arrays, you need to run `includes` on each item within your array.

This can be done using the `every` function, combined with the `includes` function, like so:

```
function isItemOmnipresent(arrayOfArrays, item) {
  // return true if the passed item is present in all the arrays inside arrayOfArrays
  return arrayOfArrays.every(childArray => childArray.includes(item));
}
```